# iPhone External Accessory help

Tags: iphone, external-accessory

I want to build an app that can communicate to some external third party hardware. I come to know that External Accessory framework can help me out in that, but I have few confusions……

1. Do I need to register ‘Made For iPod’ program before I start?
2. Do I need the third party hardware before I start, or I can start without hardware?
3. Is there any alternative to test the app, if the hardware is not currently available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could do that. But they don't approve everyone who registers like in the iOS program. It takes (in my experience) a lot of time and they have requirements that not everybody can met. You  don't need to apply if the hardware is ready. The MFI program is for hardware developers. If you don't make hardware I wouldn't even try to get into MFI. It's a waste of time and money.
   If you write an official app for the accessory, the company that makes it should give you a prototype so you can get started ASAP.
2. I would highly suggest to get the hardware. And if this is the first accessory project for you and the company then I would consider to go there and start writing the basic code on site, where you can get your hands on the developer.
3. The communication works with streams. I never tried it but I think you could write the whole protocol specific communication with network connections and then replace the networking stuff with the EASession once you have the hardware.
   If you want to test the External Accessory framework you should have a look at EADemo. I never tried (and I don't have a accessory near me to test) but I think this should work with all accessories. But in my opinion everything EA Framework related is the easy part of the whole process.

Summary: Get the hardware. If you'll get the hardware in two weeks do the User Interface part now.  If you can't get your hands on the accessory within two weeks you should beg for a prototype.

---

Regarding your comment to the other question: Test equipment is available when you are a member of MfI.

Comment: thanks for your response, it helped me a lot and cleared many things.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want legitimately produce and certify your third party hardware, you will need to apply for 'Made For iPod’ program. You will get and API and documentation to do that.
2. Unfortunately your chances to be approved are very low.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Actually I want to build an iPhone app that can communicate some external hardware, but currently I don’t have the hardware. So I want to confirm is there any thing I can do so that I can build a POC kind of thing.

Comment: if you need to use the dock connector, you need to apply. For POC purposes there is enough information on the web to get you going :) it's possible.

Comment: yes, like I have seen Apple sample code but the problem is how can I test that it will communicate to some hardware. SO is there any test accessory available to show the communication between iPhone and hardware. Please suggest I don’t have any idea about it.